# Making Start Time a static for 1 hour

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an application that updates every 30 seconds, in which a bunch of variables and startingTime is sent which I use in charting - this is done repeatedly every 30 seconds so I have a kind of live updates. I want to re-factor this such that the first startingTime received will be used for period of one hour during which subsequent startingTime will be discarded. The whole essence is to prevent the chart being redrawn every 30s but other parameter will be used to update the chart.
How to i do this in Flex builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the dataProvider will be array collection / array based you can remove the old values on the list and add new values at the end list(basically a Queue implementation of ArrayCollection).

Now after you have done this, you will do a `ArrayCollection(chart.dataprovider).refresh()`;

if you have the array collection binded to the chart, when you modify the arraycollection, this will be automatically reflected in the chart, so, the whole chart wont be repainted.